# How to configure my own NuGet package in Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm creating my own NuGet package and for it to work properly I need some configuration that each user that installs my package will set.

I noticed that some packages are configured in `Startup.cs` mostly in `Configure` and `ConfigureServices` methods.

An example is this Swagger package:

[image: Swagger configuration in Startup.cs]

In the image above, it configures the API docs name in a swagger configuration. I need something like that. In one of my classes inside my package, it will need information set by the user in Startup file.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code not a picture of your code

Comment: Yeah so hit F12 on that method or look up its source online. You need to write an extension method that accepts a `this IApplicationBuilder app` and do your thing in there.

Comment: @DalmTo I do not have the code implemented yet, I'm trying to understand how it works first.

CodeCaster, I looked into the swagger source code, but its very difficult to understand. Do you have a better example?

Comment: Here is the code for `UseSwagger`.. Hope this helps
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger/DependencyInjection/SwaggerBuilderExtensions.cs

Answer (score 0):

The methods you see in startup are simply extensions on `IServiceCollection` (for `services` in `ConfigureServices`) or `IApplicationBuilder` (for `app` in `Configure`). In other words, you'd simply create something like:

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureMyStuff(this IServiceCollection services, string someParam, string someOtherParam)
    {
        // do stuff

        return services;
    }
}
```

Then in `Startup`, the user will be able to do:

```
services.ConfigureMyStuff("some value for param", "some value for other param");
```

Comment: Thx for answer. The question is, where I pass those two parameters in the method ConfigureMyStuff inside my package? How can I get from my package that parameters you pass to?